# Can I stop Emacs from resetting default-directory every time I open a file?

Tags: find-file, directories

If I:

- Start Emacs in my home directory (`~`)
- Find a file in the `~/Projects/ruby-play` directory with `C-x C-f`
- Try to find another file with `C-x C-f`

The default directory in the file finder will be `~/Projects/ruby-play`.

What I'd like to see is the default directory being `~` still.

Thank you very much!

*P. S.* Can I maybe use some external package for it? Will Projectile do it for me, for instance?

*P. P. S.* Since, apparently, I wasn't clear enough... I don't want Emacs to return to my home directory every time. I wish to preserve *any* directory I need (e. g., if I start Emacs in the `Project` directory, I want the file finder to start in the `Project` directory as well).

Comment: I don't know how to change this behaviour, but if you used Ido mode, then selecting the home directory when looking for a file to open would only require typing `~/`.

Comment: @wvxvw Thanks! However, I'd like to have similar behavior if I, say, launched Emacs from the `Projects` directory (i.e., having the default directory always be `Projects`).

Comment: Would it be a solution to save the default directory in your init file to custom variable and then later access that custom variable instead of `default-directory`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I'm sorry, I'm an Emacs newbie. How can I reassign the file finder dialogue to a custom directory?

Comment: Keep in mind that doing such a thing will break every single package relying on this very behaviour.  I tried it out for fun and it broke smart-mode-line because it was using vc which relies on it for its widget to work normally. Please consider either using a package giving you a simple way to find a file in your home directory or something like projectile to do things from the project root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`default-directory` is a buffer local variable which can be set by all sorts of things although it is always set on loading a file. The simplest dumb solution is to use the `find-file-hook` and set it back to what you want:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'(lambda () (setq default-directory (expand-file-name "~/"))))
```

However this does have the disadvantage of always setting it to your home directory. More complex tricks are possible, so for example I have a hook in my mailer to set the directory to the relevant source tree depending on the source of the email:

```
;; Set default directory when viewing messages
(defvar my-mailing-list-dir-mapping
  '( ("qemu-devel.nongnu.org" . "~/lsrc/qemu/qemu.git/")
     ("kvmarm.lists.cs.columbia.edu" . "~/lsrc/kvm/linux.git/") )
  "Mapping from mailing lists to source tree.")

(defvar my-maildir-mapping
  '( ("linaro/virtualization/.qemu" . "~/lsrc/qemu/qemu.git/")
     ("linaro/kernel" . "~/lsrc/kvm/linux.git/") )
  "Mapping from maildirs to source tree.")

(defun my-set-view-directory ()
  "Switch the `default-directory' depending on the mailing list we
  are in."
  (interactive)
  (let ((list (mu4e-message-field (mu4e-message-at-point)
                                  :mailing-list))
        (maildir (mu4e-message-field (mu4e-message-at-point)
                                     :maildir)))
    (setq default-directory
          (expand-file-name
           (or
            (assoc-default list my-mailing-list-dir-mapping)
            (assoc-default maildir my-maildir-mapping 'string-match)
            "~"))))))

(add-hook 'mu4e-view-mode-hook 'my-set-view-directory)
```

Comment: However this does have the disadvantage of always setting it to your home directory.

There really isn't anything stopping me from saving the project name in a variable though, right?

Comment: @art-solopov: of course not, just make sure it's declared as buffer local. Most of the project management extensions will already have some sort of project-root variable that points to the top of the tree already.

Comment: Thank you @stsquad. I probably should to that before I try to implement a monstrosity of my own. =)